# Get pytest to look within the base directory of the testing script

Tags: python, pytest

In pytest, my testing script compares the calculated results with baseline results which are loaded via

```
SCRIPTLOC = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TESTBASELINE = os.path.join(SCRIPTLOC, 'baseline', 'baseline.csv')
baseline = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(TESTBASELINE)
```

Is there a non-boilerplate way to tell pytest to start looking from the root directory of the script rather than get the absolute location through SCRIPTLOC?

Comment: thisis completely unrelated to pytest, its entirely in your own code, thus entirely your responsibility

Comment: Maybe I am asking this wrongly. How does one reference relative (as in relative to the test script) directories in pytest? I put in the code to show what I have been doing to get around it.

Comment: there currently isn't, that's a standard python problem - stuff like pkgutil/pkg_ressources can help

Answer (score 14):

If you are simply looking for the pytest equivalent of using `__file__`, you can add the `request` fixture to your test and use `request.path`

From the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.path):

> ```
> class FixtureRequest
>   ...
>   property path: Path
>       Path where the test function was collected.
> ```

So an example might look like:

```
def test_script_loc(request):
    baseline = request.path.parent.joinpath('baseline', 'baseline.cvs')
    print(baseline)
```

If you're wanting to avoid boilerplate though, you're not going to gain much from doing this (assuming I understand what you mean by 'non-boilerplate')

Personally, I think using the fixture is more explicit (within pytest idioms), but I prefer to wrap the request manipulation in another fixture so I know that I'm explicitly grabbing sample test data just by looking at the method signature of a test.

---

Here's a snippet I use (modified to match your question, I use a subdirectory hierarchy):

```
# in conftest.py
import pytest

from pathlib import Path


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def script_loc(request):
    '''Return the directory of the currently running test script'''

    return request.path.parent
```

And sample usage

```
def test_script_loc(script_loc):
    baseline = script_loc.joinpath('baseline/baseline.cvs')
    print(baseline)
```

##### pytest <= 6 compatibility

I've long since stopped supporting legacy Python and instead use `pathlib`.
Given that, I no longer return `LocalPath` objects nor depend on their API, but occassionally I still need to support platforms with `pytest<=6.0` which do not yet have [the `request.path` property](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/8251/commits/22dad53a248f50f50b5e000d63a8d3c798868d98).
The pytest team is also planning to eventually deprecate `py.path` and is [porting their internals to the standard library `pathlib`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/projects/4). This started as early as pytest 3.9.0 with the introduction of `tmp_path`, though the actual removal of `LocalPath` attributes may not happen for some time.

Until you can upgrade to `pytest>=7.0`, it's easy enough to convert the `LocalPath` to a `Path` ourselves.

Here's a variant of the above example using a `Path` object, tweak as it suits you:

```
# in conftest.py
import pytest

from pathlib import Path


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def script_loc(request):
    '''Return the directory of the currently running test script'''

    return Path(request.fspath).parent
```

And sample usage

```
def test_script_loc(script_loc):
    baseline = script_loc.joinpath('baseline/baseline.cvs')
    print(baseline)
```

#### Legacy py.path

For older versions of pytest that depend on `py.path` and/or required Python 2.x support, the original version of this answer used the `request.fspath` attribute to return an instance of `py.path.LocalPath`.

From the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=request#pytest.FixtureRequest.fspath):

> ```
> class FixtureRequest
>   ...
>   fspath
>       the file system path of the test module which collected this test.
> ```

So an example might look like:

```
def test_script_loc(request):
    baseline = os.path.join(request.fspath.dirname, 'baseline', 'baseline.cvs')
    print(baseline)
```

The fixture variant might appear as follows:

```
# in conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def script_loc(request):
    '''Return the directory of the currently running test script'''

    # uses .join instead of .dirname so we get a LocalPath object instead of
    # a string. LocalPath.join calls normpath for us when joining the path
    return request.fspath.join('..')
```

And sample usage:

```
def test_script_loc(script_loc):
    baseline = script_loc.join('baseline/baseline.cvs')
    print(baseline)
```

Comment: The second example you posted doesn't seem to work, I get this error: `Fixture "get_test_workbook" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,`

Comment: @RaleighL. that error should only occur if you both forgot to add the fixture as an argument in your test function's signature and also then called the fixture directly in the function body.